# Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration - NPM run build:prod

Tags: angular, npm

I have recently upgrade Angular from 4 to 5.2.8 and also upgraded typescript to latest.

Now when I run npm run build:prod I get the following error

```
Module not found error

Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
```

and it's telling me the TS, JS and NGfactory files don't exist

Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

```
/Users/myname/Documents/Code/prizetime/assets/app/messages/messages.component.ngfactory doesn't exist
  .js
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    /Users/myname/Documents/Code/prizetime/assets/app/messages/messages.component.ngfactory.js doesn't exist
  .ts
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    /Users/myname/Documents/Code/prizetime/assets/app/messages/messages.component.ngfactory.ts doesn't exist
  as directory
```

Now from what I assume is that there is something wrong with the build script or the webpack

Webpack

```
var path = require('path');

var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common.js');

module.exports = webpackMerge.smart(commonConfig, {
    entry: {
        'app': './assets/app/main.aot.ts'
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/js/app'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/js/app/',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                    'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    'angular2-template-loader',
                    'angular-router-loader?aot=true'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: false
        })
    ]
});
```

Build script

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "build": "del-cli public/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch",
    "build:prod": "del-cli public/js/app && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail && del-cli public/js/app/**/*.js public/js/app/**/*.js.map !public/js/app/bundle.js !public/js/app/*.chunk.js assets/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts assets/app/**/*.shim.ts assets/app/**/*.ngsummary.json assets/app/**/*.ngstyle.ts"
  },
```

I think it's placing the production app in potentially the wrong folder so breaking the compiling? I've looked at similar issues and it seemed people had issues with relative path to components or imports but I can't seem to find any in my code.

I can share gitrepo it that helps?

Comment: Have the same issue.. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: If I get anywhere, i will keep you updated